# Create Method that edits values of Custom Class in Java. i.e:

Tags: java, oop

I had a quick and most likely simple question regarding the creation of a method that edits the values within the class object. Bellow is a highly simplified example. There is a a class titled "num" which contains a single integer titled obj. The `num()` method takes and assigns  the input of an integer. I am in need of a way to edit that obj value  by adding 1 that can be structured like  so:

```
num testcase=new num(4).addone();
```

or simply:

```
num(4).addone();
```

I understand there are other ways to do this but unfortunately I need it to be done like this. My desired output for this would be a new "num" object containing the integer value 5 stored in obj. Essentially I need the object to be created and then edited through the addition of 1. If anyone could either provide me a solution, give me the correct terminology for this for further research, or any help would be greatly appreciated. I understand the example below does not work but I was just giving an example.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
public static class num {
    // simple class containing single integer
    int obj; 

    public num(int input) {
        // method creating num class object 
        this.obj = input;
    }

    public addone() {
        // rudimentary attempt at creating such function. 
        this.obj = obj + 1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    num testcase = new num(4).addone();
}
```

I have tried a multitude of different ways to store the function and attempted to implement newinstance but don't quite understand this.

Comment: `testcase` would be assigned the return value of `addone()`.  What is that return value here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to do the chained method call you need your method to actually return the instance of your class itself so it can resolve to the assignment instruction.

Here:

```
public class num {

    int obj; 
    public num(int input){
        this.obj=input;
    }
    //it needs to return the instance of the class itself
    public num addone(){
        this.obj=obj+1; //modify the obj attribute
        return this;  //return the instance of the class
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        //Reason you need addone to return the instance of the class
        //is for the compile to resolve the below assignment as
        //you are assigning a Type "num" to testcase
        num testcase = new num(4).addone();
        System.out.println(testcase.obj); //this should print 5
    }
}
```

Here is a good read about it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-chaining-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: Thank you so much this is amazing. I had no idea it was called that. It's a very hard thing to describe in a google search without the correct terminology. Great help. Thank you. Will continue my research on it with this resource. Have a good one.

Comment: You are very welcome! If it helped you please consider marking it as accepted. It is the V icon on the left side of it :)